# How can print all nodes that are greater than specific node in tree?

Tags: java, tree

I make this code to search about key then print all nodes greater than this key

```
public boolean search(int data) {
    return search(root, data);
}

private boolean search(BSTnode p, int data) {
    if (p == null)
        return false;
    else {
        // if the data we are searching for is found at p (at the current    root)
        if (data == p.getData())

        return true;
        else if (data < p.getData())
        return search(p.getLeft(), data);
        else
        return search(p.getRight(), data);
    }
}
```

and I try make this code to print all nodes greater than the key

```
public void printAllNodeGreaterMyFoundNode(int data) {
    printAllNodeGreaterMyFoundNode(root, data);
}
private void printAllNodeGreaterMyFoundNode(BSTnode p, int data){

        if(data<p.getData())
        System.out.print(p.getData());
```

finally this my void main

```
System.out.print(">    What value do you want to search for: ");
            value = input.nextInt();
            if (myTree.search(value)){
            System.out.println(">    " + value + " was found in the tree and the values greater than "+value+"are:");
                            myTree.printAllNodeGreaterMyFoundNode(value);
```

Could anyone can help me please?

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: why don't not print nodes while searching?

Comment: it doesn't print the nodes that are greater than found node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by traversing the whole tree, and using a simple `if` comparator statement :

```
private void printAllNodeGreaterMyFoundNode(BSTnode p, int data){
    if(p == null){
        //do nothing reached the end
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(p.getData() >= data){
            System.out.println(p.getData());
        }
        printAllNodeGreaterMyFoundNode(p.getLeft(), data);
        printAllNodeGreaterMyFoundNode(p.getRight(), data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: When each BSTNode has access to its parent

```
public void printGreater(BSTNode root, int value) {
    BSTNode data = search(root, value);
    BSTNode succ;
    if (data != null) {
        System.out.println(">    " + value + " was found in the tree and the values greater than " + value + "are:");
        while (data != null) {
            succ = successor(data);
            if (succ != null) {
                System.out.println(succ.data);
            }
            data = succ;
        }
    }
}

private BSTNode search(BSTNode p, int data) {
    if (p == null)
        return null;
    else {
        // if the data we are searching for is found at p (at the current
        // root)
        if (data == p.data)
            return p;
        else if (data < p.data)
            return search(p.left, data);
        else
            return search(p.right, data);
    }
}
```

In the main method

```
System.out.print(">    What value do you want to search for: ");
value = input.nextInt();
printGreater(bstRootNode, value);
```

Method 2: If you don't have access to the parent node in the BSTNode class

```
public void printGreaterWithoutParent(BSTNode root, int value) {
    BSTNode data = search(root, value);
    if (data != null) {
        System.out
                .println(">    " + value + " was found in the tree and the values greater than " + value + "are:");
        greaterNodes(root, data);
    }
}

private void greaterNodes(BSTNode n, BSTNode k) {
    if (n == null)
        return;
    greaterNodes(n.left, k);
    if (n.data > k.data) {
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }
    greaterNodes(n.right, k);
}
```

In the main method

```
System.out.print(">    What value do you want to search for: ");
value = input.nextInt();
printGreaterWithoutParent(bstRootNode, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the node in BS tree, then you can just traverse on the right subtree, rooted at the searched node.